# How to query array data in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I query all the details of the table based on table name `studentdb`?

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| tags.path | tags.value | gender data
+-----------+------------+------------+
| id/name   | Ram        | male
+-----------+------------+------------+
| id/name   | Leela      | female
+-----------+------------+------------+
| id/number | 123        |  null
+-----------+------------+------------+
| id/number | 456        |  null
+-----------+------------+------------+
| id/name   | hello      |  null
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: what do you mean by "query all the details"

Comment: i actually want how many times the name Ram has occured

Answer (score 0):

> i actually want how many times the name Ram has occured – terry 3 mins ago

Depending on what's the actual schema of your table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c 
FROM `table`, UNNEST(tags) t
WHERE t.path = 'id/name' AND t.value='Ram'
```